# Filter with reduce in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
(accountid, mid, url, spent)
RDD(("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 5774),
("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 543),
("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 52),
("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 85),
("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 54),
("55E5", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 287),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 853),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 2),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 55),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 984),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 24),
("54XJ", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 57))
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 853),
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 2),
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 55),
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 984),
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 24),
("745K", 5, "https://www.google.com/", 57))
```

Lets say I have an RDD of tuples like this but they are not ordered as above. I want to return only to top 3 highest spent for each account id above.

I was thinking to order them by `.sortBy(x => (x._1, x._4))` and then doing a foldleft but I don't know how to add back to my RDD. There must be a more elegant way to do this. Also in some cases there might be exactly or less than 3 items in which case I want to keep them all.

Comment: What should the end result be?  `RDD[(accountID, Seq[spent])]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I don't know how to add back to my RDD ...

When working with Spark, you should always think about **transforming** the data into a new RDD, and not about **"updating"** some existing RDD: RDDs are *immutable* and Spark supports calculation through *transformations* of one RDD into another.

Specifically, looks like what you want to do here is to "group" your data by ID, and then apply some logic (sort and take top 3) to each resulting "group". Below are two ways to achieve this - one is a pretty straightforward implementation of this flow (group, map values using sort + take), the other is an optimization which might be critical under specific circumstances (i.e. when a single key has > thousands of records)

```
// just an alias to make things shorter to write...
type Record = (String, Int, String, Int)

// simple, but potentially slow / risky:
// groupBy "collects" all records with same key into a single record, which means
// it can't scale well if a single key has many records:
val result1: RDD[Record] = rdd.groupBy(_._1).values.flatMap(_.toList.sortBy(-_._4).take(3))

// an alternative approach that does the same, but should be faster
// and less fragile - at no point would we collect all records of a single key
// into a collection in one worker's memory. We do that by replacing "groupByKey"
// with "aggregateByKey" with functions that would keep only top 3 items per key at all times
val result2: RDD[Record] = rdd.keyBy(_._1)
  .aggregateByKey(mutable.SortedSet[Record]()(Ordering.by(-_._4)))(
    { case (list, item) => (list + item).take(3) },
    { case (list1, list2) => (list1 ++ list2).take(3) }
  ).values
  .flatMap(_.toList)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The most a single record could have in the first instance would likely be ~500k records. Would that be an issue?

Comment: 500K sounds enough to make it an issue, yes. First, there's a 2GB limit on the _partition memory size_ in Spark; 500K of these records could easily comsume ~0.5-1GB (depending on the lengths of these Strings), so 2-3 such records falling in the same partition will crash your job. And even without it, Spark will be forced to use a single core to _sort_ 500K records which will slow it down significantly.